# SNS - JSON message body failed to parse

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-sns

I am trying to send to mobile devices a remote notification through Amazon SNS. I got a database which i store the JSON (payload) which needs to be given to PublishRequest of the SNS. I serialise the json in code and pass it to the request.

The issue is that SNS fails with an error: "MESSAGE STRUCTURE - JSON MESSAGE BODY FAILED TO PARSE"

As a requirement, the service (which is responsible to communicate with SNS and send the notification) has to retrieve from DB (MySQL) the json.

What I am missing?

The database is MySQL and the service is written in .Net Core

```
string messageFromDb = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input.Payload);

var request = new PublishRequest
{
    TargetArn = endpoint.EndpointArn,
    MessageStructure = "json",
    Message = messageFromDb
};

PublishResponse publishResponse = await _client.PublishAsync(request);
```

JSON from DB:

```
{"APNS": {"aps": {"alert": "Check out the new!", "sound": "default"}, "category": {"type": "sports"}}}
```

I tried also this without any luck:

```
{"default": "something", "APNS": {"aps": {"alert": "Check out the new games!", "sound": "default"}, "game": {"type": "Xbox"}}}
```

Comment: Could you share example of JSON?

Comment: Did you try debugging, to see what you get as Payload? Also, why ae you doing `SerializeObject` 2 times? First when getting from DB, and second when populating Message? Also, did you check requirements if `MessageStructure` is json: `Message` must be a syntactically valid JSON object; and contain at least a top-level JSON key of "default" with a value that is a string.

Comment: @Caldazar considering the 2 times of serializedObject is a typo here in SO I edited the post. I am working with the rest of the comment.

Comment: I don't think `MessageStructure = "json"` means what you assume it does.  Your correct action is probably to remove this line.

Comment: I edited the question. @Michael - sqlbot if i dont include the MessageStructure = json the notiifcation will have no sound or custom keys.

Comment: Aha, well, it looks like you were trying to do something different that I assumed, so my apologies for the bad advice, and +1 for what looks like a solid answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, maybe this answer will help someone. The JSON in the DB should be

```
{"aps": {"alert": "Check out the new!", "sound": "default"}, "category": {"type": "sports"}}
```

The .Net code should be:

```
AWSRoot obj = new AWSRoot(input.Payload);

var request = new PublishRequest
{
    TargetArn = endpoint.EndpointArn,
    MessageStructure = "json",
    Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)
};

PublishResponse publishResponse = await _client.PublishAsync(request);
```

**AWSRoot**  is the root object that we create for SNS

```
public class AWSRoot
{
    public string APNS { get; set; }

    public AWSRoot(string payload) 
    {
        APNS = payload;
    }
}
```